# Improve Regex to catch complete emails from Google search?

Tags: python, regex, email, search, beautifulsoup

In order to practice and help my sister get emails from doctors for her baby, I have designed this email harvester. It makes a search, cleans the urls given, adds them to a dictionary and parse them for emails in two different ways.

The code has been taken from different places, so if you correct me, please explain clearly your improvement, as I am working at the limit of my knowledge already.

The question is how to get emails better (and improve code, if possible). I'll post the code and the exact output below:

CODE of my program:

```
import requests, re, webbrowser, bs4
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time, random, webbrowser
import urllib.request

def google_this():                #Googles and gets the first few links
    search_terms = ['Fiat','Lambrusco']
    added_terms = 'email contact? @'

    #This searches for certain keywords in Google and parses results with BS
    for el in search_terms:
        webpage = 'http://google.com/search?q=' + str(el) + str(added_terms)
        print('Searching for the terms...', el,added_terms)
        headers = {'User-agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
        res = requests.get(webpage, headers=headers)
        #res.raise_for_status()

        statusCode = res.status_code
        if statusCode == 200:
            soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
            serp_res_rawlink = soup.select('.r a')

            dicti = []                  #This gets the href links
            for link in serp_res_rawlink:
                url = link.get('href')
                if 'pdf' not in url:
                    dicti.append(url)

            dicti_url = []              #This cleans the "url?q=" from link
            for el in dicti:
                if '/url?q=' in el:
                    result = (el.strip('/url?q='))
                    dicti_url.append(result)
            #print(dicti_url)

            dicti_pretty_links = []     #This cleans the gibberish at end of url
            for el in dicti_url[0:4]:
                pretty_url = el.partition('&')[0]
                dicti_pretty_links.append(pretty_url)
            print(dicti_pretty_links)

            for el in dicti_pretty_links:   #This converts page in BS soup
                # browser = webdriver.Firefox()
                # browser.get(el)
                # print('I have been in the element below and closed the window')
                # print(el)
                # time.sleep(1)
                # browser.close()

                webpage = (el)
                headers = {'User-agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
                res = requests.get(webpage, headers=headers)
                #res.raise_for_status()
                statusCode = res.status_code
                if statusCode == 200:
                    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')

                    #This is the first way to search for an email in soup
                    emailRegex = re.compile(r'([a-zA-Z0-9_.+]+@+[a-zA-Z0-9_.+])', re.VERBOSE)
                    mo = emailRegex.findall(res.text)
                    #mo = emailRegex.findall(soup.prettify())
                    print('THIS BELOW IS REGEX')
                    print(mo)

                    #This is the second way to search for an email in soup:
                    mailtos = soup.select('a[href^=mailto]')
                    for el in mailtos:
                        print('THIS BELOW IS MAILTOS')
                        print(el.text)

    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.5,1))

google_this()
```

And here is the OUTPUT when this very same code above. As you can see, some emails seem to be found, but at cut just after the "@" symbol:

```
C:\Users\SK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe C:/Users/SK/PycharmProjects/untitled/another_temperase.py
Searching for the terms... Fiat email contact? @
['http://www.fcagroup.com/en-US/footer/Pages/contacts.aspx', 'http://www.fiat.co.uk/header-contacts', 'http://www.fiatusa.com/webselfservice/fiat/', 'https://twitter.com/nic_fincher81/status/672505531689394176']
THIS BELOW IS REGEX
['investor.relations@f', 'investor.relations@f', 'sustainability@f', 'sustainability@f', 'mediarelations@f', 'mediarelations@f']
THIS BELOW IS MAILTOS
investor.relations@fcagroup.com
THIS BELOW IS MAILTOS
sustainability@fcagroup.com
THIS BELOW IS MAILTOS
mediarelations@fcagroup.com
THIS BELOW IS REGEX
[]
THIS BELOW IS REGEX
[]
THIS BELOW IS REGEX
['nic_fincher81@y', 'nic_fincher81@y', 'nic_fincher81@y', 'nic_fincher81@y', 'nic_fincher81@y', 'nic_fincher81@y']
Searching for the terms... Lambrusco email contact? @
['http://www.labattagliola.it/%3Flang%3Den']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a more restrictive version that still catches all of the email:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9_.+]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_.+]+)
```

The problem of not catching anything after the first letter after the `@` is because the regex is missing a `+`

```
([a-zA-Z0-9_.+]+@+[a-zA-Z0-9_.+]+)
```

Originally this part `[a-zA-Z0-9_.+]` simply said to catch one of any of the following characters `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `.`, `_`,`+`.

I would also be careful about `@+` which says to catch 1 or more "@" symbols.

So a potentially valid email could look like this:

> ..................@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@.................

Comment: I was hoping you find the `@+`. I think the + inside the character class is probably a typo or a misunderstanding.

Comment: I am fairly certain that there should be: `([a-zA-Z0-9_.+]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_.+]+) ` as emails allow for only a single "@" operator.

Comment: Thank you Michal and @Casimir / Do you know why the regex would catch an email like 'nic_fincher81@y'? How can I express in regex that there must be a DOT or two dots before the end of the email? (such as info@whatever.co.uk)

Comment: My answer, `([a-zA-Z0-9_.+]+@+[a-zA-Z0-9_.+]+) `, will work and capture the entire email. The problem was a missing `+` towards the end.